# Error in HTTP call when Anonymous Authentication is turned off with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

When I tried to call the `webAPi` service in `angularJS` with **Anonymous Authentication** turned off in **IIS**, I get the below error:

```
Error: "_XMLHttpRequest cannot load <code>http://mywebsite/abc</code>. Invalid HTTP status code 401_"
```

I have not run into this issue with angularJS before. Thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: Do you require authentication for your Web API? On controller, method or global level? Can you call your Web API method directly from your browser or from a tool like Fiddler?

Comment: We require it for global level in our client application, Yes, it is working when directly from browser.